# hibernate-spatial 4.3 not found in Maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, pom.xml, spatial

I want to add `hibernate-spatial` and `postgis` to my Maven project.

This is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate.spatial.version>4.3</hibernate.spatial.version>
    <hibernate.core.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.core.version>
    <postgis-jdbc.version>2.2.0</postgis-jdbc.version>
  </properties>

  ...

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.spatial.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgis</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${postgis-jdbc.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

The references to `entity-manager` and `hibernate-core` work. But `hibernate-spatial` and `postgis-jdbc` are not found:

> org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:4.3 not found  Inspect a Maven model
>   for resolution problems.

(same error for `postgis-jdbc`)

How can I include these libraries in my project?

Answer (score 5):

The library `hibernate-spatial` is not available in the public maven repository until *5.0*. You can always check what is available by browsing http://mvnrepository.com/ (in this case http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial).

But you can add the hibernate spatial repository to your POM, which contains earlier releases of hibernate-spatial:

```xml
<project ...>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
      <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

This contains the matching `postgis-jdbc` library in version *1.5.2* as well.

Comment: Hello. If I change it to 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:6.0.0' it still does not work. Any Idea why ?

Comment: @lemario If you check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-spatial you will notice, that there is no 6.0.0, but a 6.0.0.Final and that hibernate-spatial has been moved to org.hibernate.orm. Btw "Dost not work" is not a good description of a problem.